# Photoshop CS6 issue with image quality when downsizing pasted image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, raster

I'm having an issue with Photoshop when I'm adding an image to a canvas.

You can see in this image below, I have a crisp screenshot of a section.

[image]

When I go to downsize this image within Photoshop, it starts to distort and the quality dramatically differs:

[image]

I have tried playing around with the interpolation settings in preferences:

[image]

I have tried every option, but the images just keep losing quality and I can't figure out why.

I am running Photoshop CS6 Windows 10 64-Bit, i7 Processor and a decent enough GPU. This has been working previously on this exact PC but something has changed recently and I'm not sure what it is.

If anyone has any ideas why this would be happening, I would really appreciate if you could share your findings.

Thanks

Comment: I'll give you a +1 for asking the question, which seems sensible except that the answer is going to be 'don't do this with rasterised text'  but... Do you really want your RL details out here on the wide interwebz, or is this, hopefully, just some made up info for example purposes? If the latter, please use an 077009 number, as prescribed by [Ofcom](https://www.ofcom.org.uk/phones-telecoms-and-internet/information-for-industry/numbering/numbers-for-drama)

Comment: @Tetsujin Haha, thanks for your comment. The information displayed is completely made up on my behalf, it's not tied to myself, or anyone else that I know. I like the name Paul and I like Foster's beer! But you never know, perhaps there is a Paul Foster somewhere with them exact details? Unfortunately, this has to be raster text. It's a screenshot of a physical web page and there will be multiple different "themes" if you like which will also have made up details.

Comment: It is often best to *not* treat *text* as it were a photograph. Ideally you'd set text *as text* which allows for resizing and retains any hinting for the font.

Comment: If you are reducing the image, use Bicubic Sharper.  Although it's not a good idea to rescale raster text in any raster image editor. It will inevitably lose quality. There's no real way around this. Better to retype the text. Better in fact not to use Photoshop at all. Simply retype it in Illustrator or InDesign.

Comment: Also note that it looks like you haven't pressed "Enter" to commit the transform.

Comment: Also if it's a screenshot of a web page, but you need it smaller, perhaps use the zoom in your browser - zoom out a little before taking the screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried zooming in to see if it's really distorted? Sometimes, you see things as distorted if zoomed out. Also, the file will seem to be distorted while transforming, which will look fine once you press enter.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yeah I've tried all of what you've suggested. I'm quite proficient with Photoshop, but this has threw me right off.

Comment: Alright! I tried the Interpolation options and there Bicubic automatic was giving a good result while Nearest Neighbour was causing the hard jagged pixels as shown in your image. Maybe set the option to Bicubic Automatic and restart photoshop? if you haven't already, that is.

Comment: Yeah, so I tried that - I've just tried again and still the same result. Quite frustrating! Maybe I need to do a re-install.

Comment:  before that check if /Preferences>Performance> Use Graphics Processor is checked.

Comment: Yep! it's checked. I've trawled through the photoshop documentation and stuff so I think I may just need to re-install the app. Annoying!

Comment: Right.... it gets more annoying if even after the reinstallation it's not fixed :D Hopefully it'll be fine. ✌